# Chance that one of the beans in this jar is not black?

Tags: probability

Nothing fancy here, I am just looking for an intuition check.

Jar has $1000$ beans in it. You don't know anything about the beans in the jar or where they came from. You are allowed to shake the jar and otherwise randomize it, but you can't look in of course.

You draw ten beans (not replacing them) and each one turns out to be black.

What is the probability that at least one bean in the jar is not black? (Or, equivalently, what is the probability that all the beans in the jar are black?)

I have been thinking that for a question like this, the ten drawn beans give you no information other than that there were ten beans in the jar. So to figure the probability that one bean in the jar isn't black, your only recourse is to figure out how many configurations of $990$ beans are possible (categorizing the beans as "black" and "non-black" and make that your denominator, while your numerator would be that number minus one. (So: $(2^{990} - 1) / 2^{990}$).

However, I'm worried that maybe the fact that I drew ten beans in a row, on the first try, that were all black, somehow raises the chance that all the beans in the jar are black (and hence that none are non-black). Is this so? If so, how does one figure the probability? And what's the theoretical reasoning behind this calculation?

May I ask a related question? Given the ten drawn black beans, is there a way to calculate the probability that the next bean will be black, which is not simply equivalent to calculating the chance that a bean will be black given a jar of $990$ non-specified beans? (In that latter case, if you had to assign a probability I guess it'd have to be $50/50$, though it feels weird to think of that as much more than a kind of formality...)

Answer (score 0):

You want to calculate the probability of the event $A=$ all the beans are black given the event $B=$ ten beans you have drawn are already black. Now a bean can be either black or non-black with probability $1/2$. So
$$P(A\cap B)=(1/2)^{990}$$
and
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
Since $P(B)\leq 1$, the $P(A|B)\geq (1/2)^{990}$ **as you have correctly guessed**. But then again to calculate $P(B)$ you need to have some prior idea about the color of the beans in the jar.

Comment: Thank you Abishanka Saha.

What about the probability that the next bean will be black? Someone tells me that via something called a "hypergeometric distribution" we can calculate a probability here that's pretty high. But I was thinking it would be close to 50/50 since we don't know anything about the beans in the jar other than that 10 of the thousand are black. What's the right thing to say here?